# Що значить слово 'Шум' в однойменній веснянці?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Ось частина веснянки для контексту.

> "Шум" (веснянка)
>
> Ой, нумо, нумо, заплетемо шума,
> Шума заплетемо, гуляти підемо.
> Ой, шум ходить, по воді бродить,
> А шумиха рибу ловить.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

З ["Порвали зелену шубу": про що насправді пісня "Шум" Go_A, яку Україна везе на Євробачення](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/news-55979577) на bbc.com:

> Етнограф Валерій Войтович у книзі "Міфи та легенди давньої України"
> відзначає, що "Шум" - це звертання до бога лісу Шума (або Шумлячого),
> щоб природа прокинулася навесні.
>
> У деяких південнослов'янських мовах, зокрема сербській, слово "шум"
> ("шума") до цього часу означає "ліс".
>
> Часті повтори у тексті слів з літерою "ш" ("Шума", "Шуме", "шуба") -
> це магічні заклинання, наприклад, щоб скоріше розпустилися дерева.
>
> Набагато пізніше, вже у християнські часи, веснянка "Шум"
> перетворилася просто на хоровод, який виконували на Великдень.
>
> Тоді ж, як вважав Михайло Грушевський, до пісні додали "жартівливі
> пародійні рими", коли "хоровод зійшов на просту забаву".

Дотичне:

> [Зелений шум](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC) - густий листяний покрив на деревах у лісі, а також шелест, утворюваний ним. *Трістан блукав по лісі, ловив зелений шум, хотів йому віддати своє кохання й сум* (Л. Укр., І, 1951, 409); *Зелений шум пливе над ними неначе маревом згадок, і карабінки за плечима хитає сумно коней крок* (Сос., II, 1958, 411).

Answer (score 4):

From Proto-Slavic *šumъ, що майже у всіх слов'янських мовах означає шум так само як і в українській, але на балканах, а саме у сербо-хорватській і в більшості на теренах Хорватії шум має значення *ліс*

[*šȕma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%A1uma) f (Cyrillic spelling шу̏ма)*

**Пояснення:**

> Probably related to šȗm (“noise, buzz”). According to P. Skok[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%A1uma), the term may alternatively be of paleo-Balkan origin (Illyrian or Thracian). He draws connection with Albanian proshëm, although the term is derived from Latin. However the native origin is confirmed by the onomatopoeic origin of Proto-Slavic *gajь (кирилецею гай)  (“forest”), so at most it is a phono-semantic matching of substrate.

**Думка автора:**

Білі хорвати жили довгий час на теренах сучасної України, тому шумом певно називали ліс і у нас :)